# Elastic search v5.5 Scripted Nested Function Scoring

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, nested

Hi I have a nested document structure

```
"question":{
    "questionId":{"type":"integer"},
    "userId":{"type":"integer"},
    "action": {
            "type":"nested",
            "properties": {
              "created": {"type": "date"},
              "interactionType": {"type": "text"},  //values can be answer,upvote etc
              "userId": {"type": "integer"},
              "score":{"type":"long"}
              }
   ....//other properties
  }
```

Now I want to do scoring of question on several functions. One of  the function is:

- iterate of every action and its type.

Actual query is little more complex. But bascially what I like to see is 
that this query should return me the val= sum of scores of (all/script filtered) nested structures.

```
{
  "query": {"function_score": {
    "query": {"bool": {"should": [
      {"function_score": {"boost_mode": "max",
        "query": {"terms": {
        "questionId": [
          1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
        ]
      }},
        "functions": [
          {"weight": 0}
        ]
      }},{
        "nested": {
          "path": "action",
          "query": {"bool": {"must": [
            {
            "function_score": {
              "query": {"script": {
                "script": "doc['userId'].value !=  doc['action.userId'].value"
              }},
              "functions": [
                {"weight": 0}
              ]
            }
          },{
            "function_score": {
            "query": {"bool": {"must": [
              {"terms": {
            "action.userId": [
              1100,1200,1300,1400,1500,1600,1700,1800
            ]
          }}
            ]}},
            "functions": [
              {"script_score": {
                "script": {
                  "inline": "double val=0; for(item in doc['action.score']){ val+=score;} return val;"
                }
              }}
            ]
          }}]}}
        }
      }
    ]}},
    "functions": [{
      "weight": 0}
    ],"boost_mode": "sum","score_mode":"sum" 
  }}
}  

For eg. 
question:{
    questionId:1,
    userId:1,
    action:[{
        created:null,
        interactionType: "answer",
        userId:1100,
        score:100},
     {
       created:null,
        interactionType: "upvote",
        userId:1200,
        score:10
     }]
```

Should return a val=200. But its actually returning 100.
 It might due to the reason that every nested query is executing separately. 
Can you please suggest a way to achieve this? 

Please don't suggest me to index score at question level as going ahead I'll be enhancing the script to filter out certain nested documents or other complexities in the script score inline method.

Comment: The score is averaged over number of nested documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also a property at nested level name score mode that is by default avg but that can be changed to sum to cater my needs.